# How to output just the user of a running process

Tags: awk, grep, ps

When I do `ps aux | grep mongod`, I get

```
mongod    53830  0.1  0.3 247276 27168 ?        Sl   Apr04 128:21 /var/lib/mongodb-mms-automation/mongodb-mms-monitoring-agent-5.4.4.366-1.rhel7_x86_64/mongodb-mms-monitoring-agent
mongod   104378  0.6  0.8 469384 71920 ?        Ssl  Mar22 571:03 /opt/mongodb-mms-automation/bin/mongodb-mms-automation-agent -f /etc/mongodb-mms/automation-agent.config -pidfilepath /var/run/mongodb-mms-automation/mongodb-mms-automation-agent.pid >> /var/log/mongodb-mms-automation/automation-agent-fatal.log 2>&1
mongod   104471  0.6  5.4 1993296 433624 ?      Sl   Mar22 578:03 /var/lib/mongodb-mms-automation/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.4.13/bin/mongod -f /data/mdiag/data/automation-mongod.conf
```

However, I'm only interested in outputting `user` of the third entry, which runs the actual `mongod` process. I'd like the output to be just

`mongod`

How would I tweak around `ps`, `grep`, and `awk` to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe it to awk and search:

```
 ps aux | grep mongod | awk '/bin\/mongod /{print $8}'
```

With that you can probably drop the grep and just let awk do the searching:

```
 ps aux |  awk '/bin\/mongod /{print $8}'
```

This is searching for the string "bin/mongod " anywhere in the record and then returning whatever is in the 8th position for that record.

Comment: I edited your answer to 1st position, and it worked. Solution looks slick

Answer (score 1):

Trying to use shell commands to get that user is most likely going to break. Can you start `mongod` using the PID option?

```
/var/lib/mongodb-mms-automation/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.4.13/bin/mongod -f /data/mdiag/data/automation-mongod.conf --pidfilepath /run/mongodb-pid.txt
```

Then you can simply run `ps $(cat /run/mongodb-pid.txt)` to get only the specific process you want.

Comment: Good idea. However there are many mongod processes running in prod and can't be altered.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably best to specify the pattern to match the end of the first part of the COMMAND field we are interested in.  Also, using bracket expressions in place of `\/` makes at least my eyes happier when looking at patterns for matching file paths.

```
ps aux | awk -v command=11 -v user=1 '$command ~ /[/]bin[/]mongod$/ { print $user }'
```

Comment: Thanks again, Michael. Your solution returned correct result. However I chose JNevill's answer as it was shorter.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps filter out agents?

```
$ ps aux | awk '/mongod/ && !/agent/{print $1}'
```

Comment: Good idea... can't argue with that. I'm afraid what if there are other processes I might miss filtering, since I'd need to run this against hundreds of hosts that has mongod running.

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help here.

```
ps aux | awk '/mongod/ && /automation-mongod.conf/{print $8}'
```

OR

```
ps aux | awk '/mongod/ && /\/data\/mdiag\/data\/automation-mongod.conf/{print $8}'
```